# Цикл графиков в матплотлиб

Tags: python, matplotlib

Хочу, чтобы в каждом столбце считалось количество единиц, двоек, троек и четверок и отрисовывались графики ОТДЕЛЬНО для каждого столбца.

```
1   2   1   1   2
1   1   1   0   1
1   0   1   1   1
1   3   1   0   1
1   3   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   3   1
```

Но не догоняю в этой логике матплотлиб с построением новых окон для каждого графика... казалось, что в коде и так это подразумевается. Но в итоге графики сохраняются пустыми на 0 кб

```
def autolabel(rects, labels=None, height_factor=1.01):
    for i, rect in enumerate(rects):
        height = rect.get_height()
        if labels is not None:
            try:
                label = labels[i]
            except (TypeError, KeyError):
                label = ' '
        else:
            label = '%d' % int(height)
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., height_factor*height,
                '{}'.format(label),
                ha='center', va='bottom')
for col in df.columns:
    arr = df[col]

    a = 0
    for i in arr[:]:
        if i == 1:
            a += 1

    b = 0
    for i in arr[:]:
        if i == 2:
            b += 1

    c = 0
    for i in arr[:]:
        if i == 3:
            c += 1

    d = 0
    for i in arr[:]:
        if i == 4:
            d += 1

    # counts = df.iloc[0]
    resps = ['Вариант 1', 'Вариант 2', 'Вариант 3', 'Вариант 4']
    counts = [a, b, c, d]
    print(a, b, c, d)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4)) #размеры
    patches = plt.bar(resps, counts, edgecolor='pink', width=1.0)
    jet = pl.get_cmap('PiYG', len(patches)) #увета
    autolabel(ax.patches, height_factor=1.01)
    ax.set_title('{}'.format(str(col)), loc='left')
    ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
        #ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
        #plt.axis('off')
    for i in range(len(patches)):
              patches[i].set_facecolor(jet(i))
    plt.savefig("C:/Users/Я/{}.png".format(str(col)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame({f'col_{index}' : col for index, col in enumerate([col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4])})

for index, column in enumerate(df.columns):
    array_counts = Counter(df[column])
    x,y = [], []
    for key, value in array_counts.items():
        x.append(key); y.append(value)
    
    plt.title(f'oX: {x}, oY: {y}')
    plt.xlim(-1, 5)
    plt.bar(x, y)
    plt.savefig(f'pic_{index + 1}.png')
```

Comment: спасибо, очень изящно и красиво оптимизирует код! Осталось теперь найти решение по несохраняющимся картинкам матплотлиб...

Comment: @lo lo, какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Matplotlib `RuntimeWarning` exception: Too many figures open simultaneously .     plt.clf() не помог

Comment: Во всяком случае добавил сохранение в свой код, если все же решите воспользоваться (он работает).

Comment: У меня ваш код работает, кстати. Видим что-то не так с путем, я заменил на эту строчку: plt.savefig("pic_{}.png".format(str(col)))

Comment: и все заработало.

Comment: да, Ваш работает у меня, все сохраняется отлично. Subplot использую, чтобы добавить значения на сами бары (первая функция)